# No actualiza los cambios en dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-restful

Tengo un proyecto en flask en un contenedor docker, el problema es que no actualiza los cambios, cuando modifico el código. Es decir, como lo tengo debería de actualizar y verse los cambios, de hecho cuando guardo detecta que se ha guardado y recarga el archivo segun los mensajes que veo de la terminal:

*** Detected change in '/usr/src/app/imd.py', reloading**

*** Restarting with watchdog (inotify)**

Pero no cambia el archivo, creo que podría ser que no cambie el archivo modificado.

Lo curioso es que si reinicio los contenedores no aplica los cambios **docker-compose restart**, pero si hago **docker-compose down** y despues **docker-compose up -d** si aplica los cambios.

En el dockerfile tengo:

```
# Establecemos la imagen base
FROM python:latest


ENV FLASK_APP=/usr/src/app/app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_DEBUG=1
ENV FLASK_ENV=development 
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/src/app/instantclient_21_12:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
       
COPY ./instantclient_21_12 /usr/src/app


#Server will reload itself on file changes if in dev mode

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app
RUN chmod 777 /usr/src/app/*

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libaio1

# Establecer la zona horaria copiando el archivo de zona horaria
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Madrid /etc/localtime


CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Y en el docker-compose.yml tengo:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dbmongoflaskapi:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /opt/VM/openits3.0-linux/db:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: usermongo
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: usermongo
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: db

  myflaskwebservice:
    build: /opt/VM/openits3.0-linux/webapp/.
    #command: celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info  #app coincide con el nombre del fichero app.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - /opt/VM/openits3.0-linux/webapp:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - dbmongoflaskapi      


  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

¿Tienen alguna idea de que es lo que puede estar pasando o algún consejo?

Comment: recuerda que cuando haces el docker-compose up, lo haces basado en una imagen que preciamente creaste, para que te tome los cambios debes hacer el build y luego el up,  si esto no funciona intenta hacer build desactivando cache

Comment: Vale lo probaré, ¿Como se desactiva la cache? Gracias de antemano. @JackNavaRow

Comment: [docker-compose build --no-cache](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/)

Comment: Lo he probado pero sigue igual no me actualiza bien los cambios incluso aplicando --no-cache.

Comment: Creo que es la imagen la que no hace que se actualiza bien intuyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he resuelto el problema por lo visto el servicio de docker se quedo pillado y siempre utilizaba los mismos datos que tenia en cache, la solución fue resetear los servicios del docker.